# selenium webdriver - enable cookies

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops

I am using selenium in python, chrome as browser, I enabled the cookies in the host server and in the code, it works perfect when I run it locally, however, when I run it from Azure DevOps the I encounter an issue, from the logs I see that the webdriver disable the cookies.
Here is the code I use to enable cookies:

`chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\" + getpass.getuser()+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")`

What I am missing?

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: From the browser side:
```Microsoft account symbol
We can't sign you in
Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You need to allow cookies to use this service.
Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that tell us when you're signed in. To learn how to allow cookies, check the online help in your web browser.```

From python side:
```Element {#i0116} was not present after 200 seconds!```

Comment: I suspect a path issue.  Try without that "add_argument" bit.  (By default Chrome/Chromedriver will use a temporary folder for session stuff.... that folder is deleted on quit.)  If it works without, check the path to be sure it's correct on Azure.